# Request scope in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Request scope in JSF:
I want to store objects onto the instance variables of an MPB in request scope (in the business logic) and access them fron the JSP. But I find that the request gets killed before the MPBs getters are fired while rendering the page. I do not use a  to invoke a redirect. Is there an option to persit the request object and its contents  till the getters are fired from the page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Use `@ViewScope` instead.